# Error "Unable to find an entry point named" when trying to use Win32 DLL in .Net application

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, extern

I have the following function in a DLL created in VC++.

```
static class MyClass
{
    std::string MyFunction(char *filename)
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to use this DLL in .Net application using following code I get error.

**Code:**

```
[DllImport(@"D:\Projects\MyClass\Release\MyClass.dll")]
public static extern string MyFunction(string fileName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = MyFunction(@"C:\somefile.txt");
}
```

**Error:**

> Unable to find an entry point named 'MyFunction' in DLL

I tried using the following in my DLL project in VC++ but it doesn't compile.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::string MyFunction(char *filename)
{

}
```

The error I get in this case is on "extern" keyword.

**Error**

> Linkage specification is not allowed.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You are not close, "static class" does not mean anything in C++.  C++'s interop abilities compare unfavorably to those of a stone brick.  Only a C++ compiler could ever properly interpret and destruct that returned std::string object.  And only the exact same compiler version using the exact same compile options as used to build the DLL.  It does not get better when you do it from C#.  You must either write C code to use a pinvoke declaration in C# or you must write a `public ref class` wrapper in the C++/CLI language.

Comment: Actually, `static class` does mean something in C++, but its meaning is not the same as in C#. (It creates a class visible only to the current translation unit.) But yes, returning a `std::string` is never going to work well. It is not a type that p/invoke can marshal.

Comment: So if I remove the static keyword and also change my function so it does not using "std::sting", will it work?